# Where is my fault?

Tags: c++

I tried this code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

class Tex
{
   public:
   int ii;
};

vector <Tex> tex;
vector <Tex>::iterator itexx;

int main()
{
   Tex texx;
   texx.ii = 9;
   tex.push_back(texx);

   cout << itexx->ii;
   return 0;
}
```

When I run this code, the compiler is giving me segmentation fault or rather "Program recieved SIGSEGV segmentation fault".

I don't know the meaning of this error. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: What is your code supposed to do?

Comment: Isnt it suppose to print out 9;

Comment: Ok, but the question to ask yourself in these situations is _how_ is it supposed to happen, and then verify each step of your assumptions...

Comment: `"the compiler is giving me segmentation fault"`. No. Your program is crashing with a segmentation fault. Please understand the different stages of a compiled program.

Comment: +1 from me because, even though it is a trivial mistake, there is a short, compilable example that reproduces the problem. I wish more SO questions had that.

Answer (score 5):

`itexx` is an invalid iterator. You need to make it "point" to something by assigning a valid iterator to it. For example,

```
itexx = tex.begin();
if (itexx != tex.end())
  std::cout << itexx->ii;
```

Comment: @user241621 Glad it helped. Note that caching iterators like this can be troublesome, because a vector's iterators can become invalidated when the vector grows. So you have to be careful.

Answer (score 1):

On the line `cout << itexx->ii;` you're attempting to dereference `itexx` but you haven't assigned it to anything.

At the very least you need to do something like `itexx = tex.begin();`

That should point `itexx` to the first element of the vector `tex`.